# iText PDF display marathi, hindi and different languages in android

Tags: java, android, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

How to display different languages like Marathi, Hindi or any languages in pdf using ITEXT Pdf Library in android and java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any custom font for your language but I recommend Googles Nato Fonts which support wide variety of languages which you can easily get from here `https://www.google.com/get/noto/`.

Here are some fonts link for some languages:

1. Marathi & Hindi - https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-deva
2. Telugu - https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-telu
3. Arabic - https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-arab

You can search any language and get `.tff` file from there. And put in your resources folder. For Android put in assets folder and refer font file as `assets/filename.ttf`

Now here is the sample code to set marathi font -

```
    File pdfFile = new File("marathi.pdf");
    try {
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(pdfFile);

        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
        //font
        final FontSet set = new FontSet();
        set.addFont("assets/NotoSans-Regular.ttf");
        document.setFontProvider(new FontProvider(set));
        document.setProperty(Property.FONT, new String[]{"MyFontFamilyName"});
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("अंतरिक्ष यान से दूर नीचे पृथ्वी शानदार ढंग से जगमगा रही थी ।");
        document.add(paragraph);
        document.close();
        pdfDocument.close();
        pdfWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It takes more than a font for many languages. The formatting engine must also support advanced character combining rules/liguratures.

Comment: Have you verified your code ? 
Gives me this error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid font type.

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: Not working for me